# PropertyGrid GenericList with GenericItems

Tags: c#, generics, propertygrid, collectioneditor

Is there a way to display and edit values in the PropertyGrid (and his CollectionEditor) of an object, which is derived from an abstract generic class?
I don't get the properties displayed only something like this: "IFilter´1" or "BaseFilter'1" Where IFilter is an Interface, and BaseFilter an abstract class.

All objects contained by this list:

```
List<IFilter<bool>> _activeFilter = new List<IFilter<bool>>();
```

There is one abstract class, implementing the IFilter:

```
public abstract class FilterBase<T> : IFilter<T> { ... }
```

And a few specialized implementations of the FilterBase

```
    public class SimpleBool : FilterBase<bool> {

    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

    protected override bool Process(bool input) {
        return input && BoolValue;
    }
}
```

When I add such a "SimpleBool" class to the above defined list, the PropertyGrid wont display any of the Properties.  But it displays all correct when I define an Generic List with a non generic Type.

Is there an Solution to get this work? I tryed to add some TypeConverter and an own CollectionEditor. Obviously without luck =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. But its strange.. Just add some Property to the abstract class "FilterBase", thats all.